# What is the level cap for a non-premium and non-DLC player?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlefield-premium

I don't own premium or have any DLC. Will I be stuck at level 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can play your way to the level cap on the vanilla Battlefield 4 game. The current level cap is Rank 120.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide a source to back this up?

Comment: Here is the proof: http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/anar_kh_uk/stats/447678312/ps3/

Comment: ....really now?